# How to search for multiple tags?

Tags: cloudinary

I need search all images containing two tags (AND) with the API.

I try using comma separated tags but does not work.

ej. GET /resources/image/tags/tag1%2Ctag2

Answer (score 0):

What you shared should indeed work, e.g.,:

```
curl 'https://API_KEY:API_SECRET@api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/CLOUD_NAME/resources/image/tags/hi%2Chello'
```

However, note that it'll look for all images that are tagged with **both** tag1 and tag2.